# Pulling Music Analytics Using APPLE MUSIC API

Tags: python, api, analytics, apple-music

I'm trying to pull some data for my job and I do not really k now where to start.  I need to pull Music Analytics from Apple Music via API and I need some directions.  Any help or tips are welcome.

https://help.apple.com/itc/musicanalyticsapi/#/itc120a2ce63

Comment: You need to **get authorization** and then you can make requests via the API.

Comment: Hi,  I already have authorization I just do not know how to call the api.